# Can one sample rational number from $[0, 1]$ in $\Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I learned from real analysis course that when we devide [0,1] into irrational part $I$ and rational part $R$,  we have $m(R) = 0, m(I) = 1$.

So my question is, can I say we have zero probability that we pick rational number from $[0,1]$ segment?

My friend said no but I can't find why.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218716/probabilty-of-picking-an-irrational-number) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781756/pick-any-rational-number-r-in-the-interval-from-0-1-that-the-probability-of-p?rq=1).

Comment: @ThomasShelby Thanks, So Can I say we cannot sample rational number at all in a real line In a uniform manner? is that the meaning of probability zero.